# Can't install watchman on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, linuxbrew, watchman

I can't install watchman using linuxbrew, it is showing an error :

```
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.8' failed with exit status 1
    make[1]: *** [py-build] Error 1
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/watchman20150922-20192-z5lj26/watchman-3.7.0-brew'
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've generated error logs by

```
brew gist-logs watchman --config --doctor
```

and its link is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d4f8d02f93db2e2b1c15

Please help

Comment: try : http://codeyarns.com/2015/02/10/how-to-install-and-use-watchman/

Answer (score 3):

The Best thing to Install Watchman is :

- Go to https://github.com/facebook/watchman
- Download it by selecting **Clone or Download button**
- Go to the folder where it is downloaded and extract it.
- Go inside that folder by using ***cd watchman***

---

### Follow the below commands

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential python-dev
$ ./autogen.sh 
$ ./configure 
$ make
$ sudo make install

$ watchman --version
$ echo 999999 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches  && echo 999999 | sudo tee -a  /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events && echo 999999 | sudo tee  -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances && watchman  shutdown-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know anything about linuxbrew, but this is the fundamental problem:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d4f8d02f93db2e2b1c15#file-03-make-L31-L56

It indicates that you don't have a working python development environment set up; part of the build process in watchman is to build a C extension for python to make some serialization/deserialization more efficient.

You may want/need to install python using linuxbrew to get past this.